# How to attach database using network files in MSSQL 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to attach database files from network folder `//server/DBFolder` because `mdf` file is very large. Also I've set Everyone `read/write` permissions for `mdf`, `ldf` and for root folder. 
I've ran following script:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name 
ON (Filename = '\\server\test\test.mdf'),
   (Filename = '\\server\test\test_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

And got this error:

> Directory lookup for the file "\server\test\test.mdf" failed with the
>   operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Comment: What account is used to run the SQL Server service? Using a domain account will make your life easier when accessing network resources.

Comment: I'm use windows authentication.